# Using COUNT to find number of rows in table in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, count, qsqlquery

ive tried various methods but i keep getting an object returned.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect('films.db')
cur = connection.cursor()

def createTable():

    connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FILMS(TITLE TEXT NOT NULL , YEAR INT NOT NULL,RATING INT NOT NULL,unique(TITLE))')
    connection.execute('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO FILMS VALUES(? , ? , ?)',('Middle Men','2010','6.6'))
    connection.execute("SELECT * FROM FILMS")

    row_count = cur.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM FILMS")
    print(row_count)

    cur.close()
    connection.commit()
createTable()
```

I keep getting this cursor object returned when i print the count:
sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x027CE820
is there a reason for this? is my syntax wrong?

Comment: you must count something as a column, examples: https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/functions/count.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching the whole object.  Instead of:

```
    row_count = cur.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM FILMS")
```

Do:

```
cur.execute("SELECT Count(*) FROM FILMS")
row_count = cur.fetchone()
print(row_count)
```

This will get the row that has the count in it.  If you were doing a select that had multiple rows, you could do

```
cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Or one liner: cur.execute("SELECT Count(*) from FILMS").fetchone()

Comment: Thanks a lot , i really appreciate it :)